# =と==の違いが分からない

Tags: python

下記のようなプログラムを動かすに際して、最初のx、yの定義は=一つであるにも関わらず
if以降のx、yは==で表記するのはなぜなんでしょうか？

```
x=0
y=10
if x==0 or y==0:
    print("xとyのどちらかは0です")
```

Answer (score 2):

=が1つの時は、プログラミングの場合「左辺に右辺を代入する」という意味になります。
数学のイコールを使いたい時は==を使います。

```
x=0 #　xに0を代入する
y=10 #　yに10を代入する

#もしxが0またはyが0ならば、"xとyのどちらかは0です"と出力する。
if x==0 or y==0:
    print("xとyのどちらかは0です")
```

Answer (score 1):

「変数への代入」と「左と右が同じ値かどうかの判定」の違いです。詳しくは Python のチュートリアルなどをご覧ください。